# Search Heuristic: Sum of all next nearest locations in a list of locations. Admissible?

Tags: search, heuristics

Let us take for example a problem which involves a starting location and a list of other locations. The goal is reach all these locations.

All locations are accessible to all other locations.

The search heuristic:

```
total_distance
while locations.has_next():
    find distance to nearest location
    new_location = location_chosen
    total_distance += distance
```

This is not admissible right? Just checking my understanding of this term.

For example:

```
start = (0,0)
nodeA = (0,2)
nodeB = (0,4)
nodeC = (0,-3)
```

So this would result in

```
start > nodeA > nodeB > nodeC = 2 + 2 + 7 = 11,
```

instead of

```
start > nodeC > nodeA > nodeB = 3 + 5 + 2 = 10
```